# Получение размера и чистка корзины C#

Tags: c#, windows

Есть ли какое-нибудь `API` для взаимодействия с корзиной `Windows`, средствами `C#`? Необходимо получить размер корзины, а после очистить её.

Comment: Функция SHQueryRecycleBinA (shellapi.h)

Comment: Вообще такое можно было и в google поискать https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/124/how-to-clear-the-recycle-bin-programmatically-with-c-net

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969418/how-to-programatically-clear-the-recycle-bin-under-windows

Comment: Было задано два вопроса, а не один. Вопрос с получением размера, ответ на который я не мог найти в гугле, решил по подсказке Виктора. На второй нашёл решение в гугле.

Answer (score 0):

Да есть апи (Что-то вроде этого) - Вот инструкция -> https://csharpcoderr.com/1484/